# Scalar product matrix application (own example)

Tags: linear-algebra

I posted in another thread the following question:

> Let $V$ be the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ whose basis is $(\sin(t),\cos(t))$. Let the scalar product be defined by $$\langle f,g \rangle =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm dt$$ What is the matrix of this scalar product with respect to the given basis?

I solved it after following the tips of people in the website, however I do not know if my solution is right.
The matrix I found is:

\begin{bmatrix}\pi&2\pi\\2\pi&pi\end{bmatrix}

I tried to do an application of this finding to solve the following scalar product:

$\langle(5\sin (t)+6\cos(t),8\sin (t)+12\cos(t)\rangle=\int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi}(5\sin (t)+6\cos(t))(8\sin (t)+12\cos(t))\ dt=112\pi$

However if I solve using the scalar product matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}5&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\pi&2\pi\\2\pi&pi\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}8\\12\end{bmatrix} =328\pi$

**Questions**:

**1)** Is there  anything wrong with my application?

**2)** Is this scalar product matrix supposed to be applied this way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:By integration by parts You get

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin(t)cos(t)dt=\underbrace{-cos^2(t)]_{-\pi}^{\pi}}_{=0}-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin(t)cos(t)dt$
and thus $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin(t)cos(t)dt=0$.
So Your matrix is 
$\begin{pmatrix}\pi&0\\0&\pi\end{pmatrix}$.

For the second question:
Yes the matrix can be used to calculate the inner product in exactly this way.

Comment: It was another integral I compute, I thought it was the same and replaced the wrong value. Thanks for identifying the typo.